# Почему дублируется доменное имя в адресной строке сайта

Tags: wordpress, ссылки, домен, дублирование

Имеется сайт на WordPress.
Проблема в дублирующийся ссылке в адресной строке, как на странице сайта, так и в админке сайта.
Пример: Заходим на сайт (ggg.su) - все работает
На сайте переходим на вкладку "Новости", происходит такая ситуация (ggg.su/ggg.su/новость)
И такая же ситуация в админке WP (ggg.su/wp-admin/ggg.su/wp-admin/плагины)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если в ручную удалить дублирующийся часть, то все работает и страница загрузится.
Проблема началась после переезда сайта на другой домен.

В .htaccess никаких редиректов не указанно.

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? Куда копать?
Знания в этой сфере слабы.

Comment: Копать в свой код где вы генерите ссылки без протокола

Comment: Неправильно прописаны адреса. Не правильно перенесён сайт. См https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562